# quartely payment

Tags: finance

A Loan of R65 000 with an interest rate of 16% per annum compounded quartely is to be amortised by equal quartely payments over 3 years

Question : how do I calculate the size of the quartely payment?

Will I = 0,016/4 and will n =36 months (3years)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this question you can use the formula $A=P(1+\frac rn)^{nt}$. Where $P$ is your loan amount, $r$ is the rate, $n$ is the number of times compounded per year, and $t$ is the number of years.

In your case you would use $65000(1+\frac{.16}{4})^{4(3)}$.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you :) ok I got (1+0.16/4)^12 which = 1.60103222 do I then say 65 000 ÷ 1.60103222? Or do X it?

Comment: You would multiply the 65000 to it, and that answer would give you your total money owed or the amount you would need to pay by the end of 3 years.

Comment: Ok I got 104067.9 now to get the quartely payment do I divide that by 12 considering there's 4 quarters in a year and 3 years all together?

Comment: That is what I would do.

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle{%
 r \equiv 3\times\left(16/1200\right).\quad x_{0} \equiv 65,000.\quad
 n \equiv 12.\quad x \equiv \mbox{quarterly payment}\ =\, ?}$

\begin{align}
&\\[5mm]
x_{1} &= x_{0}\left(1 + r\right) - x
\\[1mm]
x_{2}
&=
x_{1}\left(1 + r\right) - x
=
x_{0}\left(1 + r\right)^{2} - x\left(1 + r\right) - x
\\[1mm]
x_{3}
&=
x_{2}\left(1 + r\right) - x
=
x_{0}\left(1 + r\right)^{3} - x\left(1 + r\right)^{2} - x\left(1 + r\right) - x
\\[1mm]\vdots &= \vdots
\\
x_{n}
&=
x_{0}\left(1 + r\right)^{n} - x\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}\left(1 + r\right)^{k}
=
x_{0}\left(1 + r\right)^{n} - x\,{\left(1 + r\right)^{n} - 1 \over r}
\end{align}

$x_{n} = 0\quad\Longrightarrow$

$$
\begin{array}{|c|}\hline\\
\color{#ff0000}{
{\large%
x
=
{r \over 1 - \left(1 + r\right)^{-n}}\ x_{0}}}
\\ \\\hline
\end{array}
$$